# Can you unpack an Adobe AIR app?

Tags: air

I was wondering if/how an Adobe AIR app could be unpacked so I can check out how it was implemented.  Do I need the SDK to unpack it, or is it a renamed .zip file like a .gadget file?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As far as I remember it's just a zip.

Comment: Please tell that, "In Windows", Where does the (Source Code - HTML, CSS & Javascript) of a "Adobe AIR Desktop App" Reside??

Comment: Just rename the .air to .zip, then unzip.